# Alter column type character varying(3) to boolean without losing data

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl, alter-table

I am using postgres. I created one table `xyz` having one of the column `abc` of type `character varying(3)`. I saved `'YES'` or `'NO'` in `abc` column.

I stored data in table for some time. But now requirement has changed. We need to change `abc` column type from `character varying(3)` to `boolean`.

Can there is any way we can alter `abc` type from `character varying(3)` to `boolean` and change data `YES` to `true` and `NO` to `false`?

Please help me out otherwise how can I proceed if we don't want to lose our data.

I use query

```
ALTER TABLE xyz ALTER abc TYPE boolean
USING CASE abc WHEN 'YES' THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END;
```

but it is not working, it throw error cannot be cast automatically to type boolean

Answer (score 7):

You're missing a space between `abc` and `WHEN`:

```
ALTER TABLE xyz ALTER abc TYPE boolean
USING CASE abc WHEN 'YES' THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END;
-- Here ------^
```

Also, you may want to make sure that only `'YES'` and `'NO'` are translated to booleans:

```
ALTER TABLE xyz ALTER abc TYPE boolean
USING CASE abc WHEN 'YES' THEN TRUE 
               WHEN 'NO'  THEN FALSE 
      END;
```

Comment: or shorter: `... using abc = 'YES'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's definitely a neat shorthand for the first option. It doesn't add the safety of only handling `'YES'` and `'NO'` though.